# Why is the movie title "Brick"?

Tags: title, brick

In *Brick (2005)*, the Movie is all about murder of Emily Kostich.

So why is the title *Brick* and not *Emily*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the major component of the movie's story is about missing heroin...

> The title refers to a block of heroin, compressed roughly to the size and shape of a brick.

...

> At The Pin's house, Tug tells Brendan that The Pin received a shipment of ten bricks and sold eight; **one was stolen and replaced with another that had been doctored with detergent, causing Frisco's coma, and the 10th brick remains to be sold.**
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_(film))</sup>